# How to insert a variable into an xslt document function

Tags: xml, xslt, variables, document

ok, sorry. I have this two xml files.
ProvlaLingua1.xml

```
<VENDOR>
    <IMMAGINI_SITO>True</IMMAGINI_SITO>
    <VERSIONE_SKYWALKER>1</VERSIONE_SKYWALKER>
    <CDLINGUA>IT</CDLINGUA>
</VENDOR>
```

and this second ProvaLingua2.xml

```
    <LINGUA>
          <EN>
              <TAG1>The book is on the table</TAG1>
              <TAG2>The cat is on the table</TAG2>
          </EN>
          <IT>
              <TAG1>Il libro è sul tavolo</TAG1>
              <TAG2>Finche la barca va lasciala andare</TAG2>
           </IT>
</LINGUA>
```

so I need to check ProvaLingua1 to get the CDLINGUA valor and then extract a valor from ProvaLingua2.
I need something like

```
<xsl:variable name="LANGUAGE" select="document('ProvaLingua1.xml')VENDOR/CDLINGUA"/>
<xsl:value-of select="document('ProvaLingua2.xml')/LINGUA/A VARIABLE HERE/TAG2" />
```

I need to put variable "LANGUAGE" to get an extraction, I can't do it with:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$language='IT'">

        <xsl:value-of select="document('ProvaLingua2.xml')/LINGUA/IT/TAG1" /><br />
        <xsl:value-of select="document('ProvaLingua.xml')/LINGUA/IT/TAG2" /><br />
    </xsl:when>

</xsl:choose>
```

because otherwise I'd need to write too many rows for any language.
Thank you for any help

Comment: Consider to post enough information allowing us to reproduce the problem. Your first sample with `document(ProvaLingua1.xml)` needs to be `document('ProvaLingua1.xml')` so it is difficult to judge the remaining code. You can certainly use a variable in an XPath expression the way you do in `document('ProvaLingua2.xml')/MYFILE/*[name()=$lingua]/TAG2`, to allow us to help why that does not find the node you are looking for we need to see the relevant document samples.

Comment: Did any of these two answers solved your problem? Please be kindly and mark them as answered: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't identify the problem with what you had in your post before the edit but based on your samples I show three ways to solve that, one with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 without using a key, one for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 with using a key and one with XSLT 2.0 using a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="url1" select="'test2012050202.xml'"/>
  <xsl:param name="url2" select="'test2012050203.xml'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($url1)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($url2)"/>

  <xsl:key name="tag-by-lang" match="TAG2" use="local-name(..)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xslt2>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('tag-by-lang', $doc1/VENDOR/CDLINGUA, $doc2)"/>
    </xslt2>
    <xslt1>
      <xsl:for-each select="$doc2">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('tag-by-lang', $doc1/VENDOR/CDLINGUA)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xslt1>
    <without-key>
      <xsl:value-of select="$doc2/LINGUA/*[local-name() = $doc1/VENDOR/CDLINGUA]/TAG2"/>
    </without-key>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  document('ProvaLingua2.xml')/LINGUA/*[name()=$language]/TAG1" /><br />
```